# SQL get common value in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 results set like below and I want expected result the combination of both of them. result set may be more than 2.

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`LEFT JOIN`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)

```
SELECT T.Id, T.CusType, T.SumA, L.SumB
FROm ResultSet1 T LEFT JOIN ResultSet2 L ON T.CusType = L.CusType AND T.Id = L.ID
```